# How do I target a specific project with a non-unique name when using the Package Manager (nuget)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget-package

I know about '-project' but what if I have multiple projects in my solution that have the *same* name? They're in different folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use: `Scaffold Controller FolderName\ProjectName`

Also if you look in the Package Manager Console there is the dropdown for Default Project. If you click the dropdown you can see what each of your project names would be.